# G++ Asm inline: register clobbering

Tags: assembly, g++, sse, inline-assembly, avx

Does gcc compiler use push/pop for register backup if I dont write anything in clobber list? What happens for input and output list registers?

I will make a short asm inline that saves some general purpose registers to XMM/YMM registers then plays on general purpose registers. In the end, original values are returned from XMM/YMM registers to general purpose ones. Would compiler put push/pops to save them anyway?

How can I tell GCC compiler: "dont push/pop enything for me, I am using XMM/YMM for that purpose . Maybe I will do push/pops myself"

Something like:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"
        "movd xmm0,eax \n\t"//storing in xmm registers instead of   pushing
        "movd xmm1,ebx \n\t"
        "movd xmm2,ecx \n\t"
        "movd xmm3,edx \n\t"
        "movd xmm4,edi \n\t" // end of  backups
        //.
        //... doing work
        //.
        "movd edi,xmm4 \n\t"
        "movd edx,xmm3 \n\t"
        "movd ecx,xmm2 \n\t"
        "movd ebx,xmm1 \n\t"
        "movd eax,xmm0 \n\t" // end of pops

        ://outputs
        "=g"(x[0]),  //%0
        "=g"(x[1])   //%1
        ://inputs
        "g"(x[0]),  //%2
        "g"(x[1])   //%3
        ://no clobber list
    );
```

or something like this(I know this swapping is extremely slow, just wanted to have push pops working):

```
__asm__ __volatile__ (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix \n\t"
        "push rax \n\t"
        "push rbx \n\t"
        "push rcx \n\t"
        "push rdx \n\t"

        "mov eax,%2 \n\t"
        "mov ecx,%3 \n\t"
        "mov edx,eax \n\t"
        "mov eax,ecx \n\t"
        "mov ecx,edx \n\t"
        "mov %0,eax \n\t"
        "mov %1,ecx \n\t"

        "pop rdx \n\t"
        "pop rcx \n\t"
        "pop rbx \n\t"
        "pop rax \n\t"

        ://outputs
        "=g"(x[0]),  //%0
        "=g"(x[1])   //%1
        ://inputs
        "g"(x[0]),  //%2
        "g"(x[1])   //%3
        ://no clobber list
    );
```

Comment: The compiler wants to "own" the XMM regs just like the regular general-purpose ones. You cannot simply use them from inline assembly unless you tell the compiler either: your inline assembly is expecting values in XMM regs as input/output operands, or: by _explicitly_ listing the regs you wish to modify in the clobber list_. If you do this, then there's no need whatsoever to `push`/`pop` yourself. The compiler will automatically insert such code before/after your inline asm statement if (and only if) it chose to put any variable into one of the registers you've stated you'd modify.

Comment: Okay, do I show them as "YMM0","YMM16" ? Is it possible for the  overhead of saving/restoring registers being less than overhead of JNI call?

Comment: Yes, theoretically you can list all vector regs in the clobber list. But that's wasteful and likely unnecessary ... it depends on your exact usecase whether inline assembler or a completely separate function all-written-in-assembler is better. Constructed artifical testcases can be found for either ... need to know more about the real problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: I sense a misunderstanding ... GCC inline assembly is _very different_ from MSVC. In the latter (no 64bit) the compiler did "nothing" for you regarding preservation/restoration of "C program state" before/after inline assembly blocks. with MSVC `_asm:` you had to use `push`/`pop` for regs you were planning to use. That's not the case for gcc inline asm; if your asm is fine using no more regs than you have inputs / outputs, you need no clobber list at all. You can use 'temp' vars as inputs to "get a reg". Only if you _must_ use a register explicitly by its name, you must list it as clobbered.

Comment: Also note that at least on UN*X, you'll break the ABI if you `push` from within inline assembly blocks. That's because leaf functions on 64bit x86 UN*X are allowed to use `-128(%rsp) ... (%rsp)` without having to explicitly adjust the stackpointer (the so-called _red zone_), and if you'd `push` from within a leaf function you may clobber local variables of the func your `asm()` is in. You can likewise not `call` from within inline assembly blocks.

Comment: Thanks, was very helpful. Im inclined to intrinsics for now. Do some group of intrinsics need to be in a volatile body as this asm example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is kind of tricky. As far as I know, the way you compile will have impact on the result. I am not sure if this is what you need but if you don't use inline assembly, you can control it.

You write your code in a separate .s file, and compile with optimization like -O3, gcc will not push and protect nonvolatile registers. I don't use inline assembly myself so I am not clear with that part. You can test it yourself :D

BTW: I think if you write .asm file and use nasm to compile it and link the object with gcc, same thing would happen. With optimization, I don't think gcc will do the push/pop automatically. Let me know if there are something wrong in my reply. Thanks.

Good luck

xiangpisaiMM

Comment: Linking c++ to java(through JNI and g++ compiler) was above my head(I hardly managed to do) now you are telling me to link c++ and assembly just like same :D . Okay , will try with -O3.

Comment: It worked! OMG -o3 is an optimization that lets me do whatever I want in asm inline.

Comment: Separate `.s` file is very very different from embedding the same code inside inline assembler; to start with, performing a function call _tells the compiler_ that certain registers cannot be guaranteed to retain their values when the function call returns. Code may not assume that any of the XMM regs, nor any of the argument regs (`RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8` and `R9`), nor `RAX`, are preserved post a `call` instruction. Hence, if your assembly function only uses any of these, there is no need to ever `push`/`pop` anything - as long as you have a _separate function_.

Comment: What you say is for 64 bit windows that I have.?

Comment: For Windows 64bit, similar rules apply, just the integer argument registers are `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8` and `R9`, the return value is still `RAX` and you're still under no obligation to preserve any of the `XMM` regs (or, if you've got an AVX-capable CPU, the `YMM` regs). In short, if you can have a separate function for your asm code, you need no "clobber" specs / need not worry about saving/restoring regs as long as you can limit yourself to using only the above five (Windows) resp. seven (UN*X) general-purpose regs, plus any of the vector regs.